# Set an exception handler for all exceptions thrown inside class?

Tags: php, class, exception

I know it is possible to set your own global exception handler using set_exception_handler(). But is it possible to set an exception handler inside a class, and only catch those exceptions thrown inside the class itself? I'm using a static class, if it makes any difference.

I want to do something like this (i.e. I'm looking for the "set_class_exception_handler()" function):

```
class DB{

    $dbh = NULL;

    public static function connect( $host, $database, $username, $password, $db_type = 'mysql' ){
        static::$dbh = new PDO( $db_type.':host='.$host.';dbname='.$database, $username, $password );
    }

    public static function init(){
        set_class_exception_handler( array("DB", "e_handler") );
    }

    public static function e_handler($e){
        /* Log exception */
    }

    public static function test(){
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELET username FROM users WHERE id=:id");
        // SELECT is misspelled and will result in a PDOException being thrown
    }

}

DB::init();
DB::connect( 'localhost', 'database', 'username', 'password' );
DB::test();
```

The above code should result in the exception getting logged, but an exception thrown elsewhere in the application should be handled by the default exception handler and not be logged. Is this possible somehow? The bottom line of it all is that I don't want to have to wrap everything i do in the DB class in try/catch statements to be able to log any exception.

Or is possible to redirect only certain types of Exceptions to an exception handler, and let all others go to the default handler? It seems that it's only possible to either redirect all exceptions or none to a custom exception handler using set_exception_handler()?

Comment: The root cause of your problem is using static class functions, not the exception handler.

Comment: Static classes are a collection of global functions - like the global exception handler. To learn about the type of exception expression you would need to backtrace, but much more direct is it to solve this with the type of exception - but type of exception expressions need non-global, concrete types. Concrete types are a different concept than static classes, so the root cause are the static classes which are merely a collection of functions and they have not much to do with object oriented programming of which exceptions are part of. You better just return `FALSE` in case of an error maybe.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, you should be able to do the following (untested):

```
class DBException extends Exception
{
    public function __construct($message = null, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);

        error_log($message);
    }
}

class DB
{
    public static function test() {
        
        // We overrode the constructor of the DBException class
        // which will automatically log any DBexceptions, but will not autolog 
        // any other exceptions
        throw new DBException('Something bad happened.');
    }
}

// Calling code

// This will throw fatal due to uncaught exception
// Because we are not handling the thrown exception
DB::test();
```

**-- Update --**

According to your comment, your code snippet is very close. There is no function `set_class_exception_handler`, try changing it to `set_exception_handler`. Not sure if you already read this, but there is a comment associated to the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) for `set_exception_handler` which uses static methods and appears to work. The comment was posted by "marques at displague dot com".

Comment: It seems I was a bit unclear about what I wanted to accomplish. My DB class is a wrapper for a PDO database, and I want to catch those PDOExceptions without having to do try/catch all over the place. Your solution would work, but to catch PDOException's I would still have to use try/catch and from there throw a DBException or call my log function somehow... right?

I edited the code in my original post to better reflect what I actually want to accomplish.